# Are the subspaces $(0,1)$ and $[0,1)$ of $\mathbb{R}$ isometric?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Are the subspaces $(0,1)$ and $[0,1)$ of $\mathbb{R}$ isometric$?$

I think that this is false but I cannot figure out why.

*Progress*. I see that I can remove $0$ from $[0,1)$ and this creates a non-disjoint set. I also see how removing any point from $(0,1)$ creates a disjoint set and thus we have two sets with differing topological properties and hence no homeomorphism can exist between the two. What I am not sure of is why no homeomorphism implies no isometry.

Comment: What is your definition of isometric?

Comment: The definition I am working from is this: If $(X,d_{X}), (Y,d_{Y})$ are metric spaces, a bijection $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is an isometry if $d_{Y}(f(x_{1}),f(x_{2})) = d_{X}(x_{1},x_{2})$ for all $x_{1},x_{2} \in X$.

Comment: I would show the two spaces are not homeomorphic.  Hint: Look for points that do not disconnect the space when removed.

Comment: I see that I can remove 0 from $[0,1)$ and this creates a non-disjoint set.  I also see how removing any point from $(0,1)$ creates a disjoint set and thus we have two sets with differing topological properties and hence no homeomorphism can exist between the two.  What I am not sure of is why no homeomorphism implies no isometry. Just FYI, the definition of homeomorphism I am working from is as follows: A bijection $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a homeomorphism if $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are both continuous.

Comment: An isometry is a homeomorphism that doesn't 'stretch'.

Comment: If you didn't previously know that every isometry is a homeomorphism, then it would be a good exercise to prove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space $X:=(0,1)$ has the following property: For all $x\in X$ there are points $u$, $v\in X$ different from $x$ with $d(u,v)=d(u,x)+d(x,v)$.

This is violated for the space $Y:=[0,1)$.

Answer (score 3):

An isometry is a special kind of homeomorphism. Since you've proved that the spaces are not homeomorphic, meaning no homeomorphism exists between them, then no isometry exists between them, meaning they are not isometric.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:(0,1)\rightarrow [0,1)$ be an isometry, so 
$$d(x,f^{-1}(0))=d(f(x),0)$$ 
then the equation $d(x,f^{-1}(0))=\epsilon$ has two unique solutions in $(0,1)$ for some $\epsilon>0$ but  the  $d(f(x),0)$ has only one solution in $[0,1)$.